# IPv6 private network adressing

Tags: ipv6

While sniffing a training network with Wireshark, I realized that it contains some IPv6 addresses.

So I decided to nmap one of the IPv6 address found (with the **-6** option), and was able to see my own IPv6 address on the network.

Is there an equivalent type of addressing IPv6 compared to IPv4, that is to say, if my IPV6 address is: fe80::6197:27:66c:d8e

What range of address would the private network be?

Could it be?

```
fe80::6197:27:66c:0000/112
```

or another format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address you show is a link-local address (`fe80::/10`). Those appear on any network and are non-routable. That means they are for local communication on your LAN only. They are commonly used for things like neighbor discovery, auto-configuration mDNS and streaming from one device to another (i.e. Apple TV).

Link-local addresses are somewhat similar to APIPA (`169.254.0.0/16`) addresses in IPv4.

If you're looking for private addresses then you want the [ULA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) range: `fc00::/7`. The first half of that range (`fc00::/8`) is still reserved, but the second half (`fd00::/8`) is commonly used on home networks and also on other networks that are not connected to the internet.